# Show uipicker instead of keyboard for textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uipicker

I am trying to hide a keyboard and show up a uipicker instead for  textfield.

But it seems like I am in the wrong direction or there's something wrong with my coding as 
the keyboard still persistently show up (uipicker can be seen after another view is bring forward). I supposed there is nothing wrong with my uipicker methods as the uipicker is showing correctly just that the keyboard is still blocking it. Can anyone point out which part of the code went wrong or guide me to the right direction?

Here are my codes in the textFieldDidBeginEditing method:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];

[pickerView setHidden:NO];

pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 180, 300, 180)];

pickerView.delegate = self;

pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

Please let me know if there's is any need for more codes.

Thanks

Comment: use a button that opens the picker view instead of text field

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to set the picker view as the text field's input view:

```
textField.inputView = pickerView;
```